# Is there a way to convert Armadillo vector to a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, std, armadillo, vec

I was wondering if there is a way to convert an Armadillo vector to a std string. For example if I have this vector:

```
arma::vec myvec("1 2 3"); //create a vector of length 3
```

How can I produce:

```
std::string mystring("1 2 3");
```

from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of [ostringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream), [.raw_print()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#raw_print), [.st()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#t_st_members), [.substr()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), as below.

```
// vec is a column vector, or use rowvec to declare a row vector
arma::vec myvec("1.2 2.3 3.4");  

std::ostringstream ss;

// .st() to transpose column vector into row vector
myvec.st().raw_print(ss);  

// get string version of vector with an end-of-line character at end
std::string s1 = ss.str();

// remove the end-of-line character at end
std::string s2 = s1.substr(0, (s1.size() > 0) ? (s1.size()-1) : 0);
```

If you want to change the formatting, look into [fmtflags](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags):

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss.precision(11);
ss.setf(std::ios::fixed);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
std::ostringstream s;
s << myvec;
std::string mystring = s.str();
```

Comment: Fabulous, thanks! Do you know why when I print it, it shows up as a column vector rather than characters in a row? How can I get it to be of the latter form?

Comment: To clarify, if I do 

for(int i=0;i<mystring.size();i++)
cout<<"Element "<<i<<": "<<mystring[i]<<endl;

I get a lot of unnecessary empty spaces (seem to come in 3), how can I avoid them with the exception of one empty space between the elements?

Comment: Oops. That'It shows up as a column vector because `vec` is a column vector. You could always transpose it, I guess.